# subprocess call's env passing

Tags: python

i write a python script as bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, subprocess
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PASSWD'] = "hello jian"
retcode = subprocess.call("smbclient -L //10.60.1.11  -U Mikejian"),env=env)
print retcode
```

as i execute it , it works fine ,get retcode is 0, you know , i pass the password as an environment variable,so the python will not ask me for it .

it's ok 。

now , i want to move this code to MoinMoin's (a wiki engine) code . which in a class named User, as a function bellow

```
def _validateSMBPassword(self, username, password):
    debug("call _validateSMBPassword %s:%s " % (username, password))
    import subprocess, os, shlex
    cmd = "sudo smbclient -L //%(server)s -U %(user)s"
    cmd = cmd % {
        'server' : "10.60.1.11",
        'user' : "Mikejian",
        }
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['PASSWD'] = "hello jian"
    retcode = subprocess.call("smbclient -L //10.60.1.11  -U Mikejian",env=env,shell=True)
    debug("retcode:%d" % retcode)
    if retcode == 0:
        return True, True
    return False, False
```

in this case , i always got retcode is 1 ,not 0, it seemed that the env has not past the PASSWD environment variable.

could you tell me why ?and any solution suggestion?

Comment: Env is passed inside the process, so if run your code in moinmoin, you need to make sure moinmoin actually get the environment you are expecting: how did you start moinmoin ? Note also that passing password like you do is a terrible idea for many reasons, including security.

Answer (score 0):

Can I shamelessy suggest [`pysmbclient`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySmbClient)? It's a dirty hack I wrote to replace some shell scripts at work, but it works fine for me.

```
>>> smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server="MYSERVER", share="MYSHARE", 
...     username='foo', password='bar', domain='baz')
...
>>> print smb.listdir("/")
[u'file1.txt', u'file2.txt']
>>> f = smb.open('/file1.txt')
>>> data = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> smb.rename(u'/file1.txt', u'/file1.old')
```

Comment: thank you , but access file or list file is not my purpose,i just want to use windows server to verify the user and password , instead using the default user/password verify mechanism of local MoinMoin wiki.you source code is useful .

Comment: @mike: Yeah, I use an authentication file, which is `smbclient` recommended way of passing auth information securely. You could use `pysmbclient` just for checking username/password, too.